# Steam complains that I need to have execute permissions on new Steam Library over CIFS, yet I do?

Tags: permissions, samba, steam, cifs

So I get this when I try adding a new Steam Library as a CIFS share:

(I need 10 rep to post images)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gD9d.jpg

Here is the relevant line in my /etc/fstab configuration:

```
# CIFS share on FILESERVER
//<My Share IP>/Data    /home/offensive/Media/data  cifs    credentials=/home/offensive/.fileservercredentials,noserverino,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,rw 0   2
```

As you can see, files and directories have execute permissions:

```
offensive@Offensive-Ubuntu:~$ ls -la Media/data/
total 24
drwxrwx--- 2 offensive offensive  4096 Jan 16 23:41 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 offensive offensive     8 Jan 16 23:36 ..
drwxrwx--- 2 offensive offensive     0 Jan  3 17:23 Programs
drwxrwx--- 2 offensive offensive     0 Jan 17 00:07 Storage
-rwxrwx--- 1 offensive offensive 17920 Nov  4 20:58 Thumbs.db
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should mention that even though 'other' doesn't have permission to do anything, Steam doesn't fall under the 'other' category since I am able to still modify and read the cifs share directories.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34822/is-it-possible-to-enable-execution-of-files-from-a-cifs-mount-in-bash

Comment: Yeah, if you notice, I do have exec after user in my fstab.